# Word Wrapping not working in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, word-wrap

The word wrapping method provided for JTextArea is not working in my program. Why isn't it working? How can I fix it? Here is the code:

```
    text= new JTextArea(15,65);

    text.setWrapStyleWord(true); // word wrapping enabled

    text.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(getPreferredSize()));
```

Here is the screenshot. The last word goes out of frame.
[image]

Comment: There's still a bit you're not telling us: Did you call `setLineWrap(true)` on your JTextArea? I don't see this posted anywhere. Did you place your JTextArea inside of a JScrollPane? Are you using layout managers correctly and avoiding use of null layout and absolute positioning?

Comment: I would even go further than HFOE, posting 3 lines of code is no proof of a problem nor of a solution. Only an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) can truly help you or help us find a solution for you. First thing you should do anyway is drop this call: `text.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(getPreferredSize()));`. This is just looking for troubles...(and by the way the call to the copy-constructor of Dimension is absolutely unnecessary)

Comment: thanks Hovercraft Full OF Eels I didn't use setLineWrap() method. It solved my problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following SSCCE let you experiment with both settings. Here you can see that using `setWrapStyleWord` has no effect if you do not call `setLineWrap` first. This is also documented in the javadoc of `setWrapStyleWord`.

The best results for a readable form is setting them both to true.

[image]

```
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

public class TextAreaDemo {

  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        JFrame testFrame = new JFrame( "TestFrame" );

        final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea( 15, 65 );
        testFrame.add( new JScrollPane( textArea ) );

        final JCheckBox wordWrap = new JCheckBox( "word wrap" );
        wordWrap.setSelected( textArea.getWrapStyleWord() );
        wordWrap.addItemListener( new ItemListener() {
          @Override
          public void itemStateChanged( ItemEvent e ) {
            textArea.setWrapStyleWord( wordWrap.isSelected() );
          }
        } );
        testFrame.add( wordWrap, BorderLayout.NORTH );
        final JCheckBox lineWrap = new JCheckBox( "line wrap" );
        lineWrap.setSelected( textArea.getLineWrap() );
        lineWrap.addItemListener( new ItemListener() {
          @Override
          public void itemStateChanged( ItemEvent e ) {
            textArea.setLineWrap( lineWrap.isSelected() );
          }
        } );
        testFrame.add( lineWrap, BorderLayout.SOUTH );

        testFrame.pack();
        testFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation( WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );
        testFrame.setVisible( true );
      }
    } );

  }
}
```

Comment: @Alfred shot, runnable, compilable, just about desciber idea :-)